# How to access a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php. I am able to fetch the records from database and storing them into an array. Array contains more than one values for each array index. Now I want to fetch only one value. Here is my array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [center_id] => 103 [center_strength] => 800 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [center_id] => 102 [center_strength] => 400 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [center_id] => 101 [center_strength] => 200 ) 
      )
```

From this array I want to get the value of `[center_strength]` only i.e. only `800`. Please Help me :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Comment: `$your_array[0]['center_strength']`

Comment: This code worked for me. Thank You Very Much @Don't Panic. You are savior man. Thanks a Lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Printing all the keys and values one by one
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
     echo $keys[$i] . "{<br>";
     foreach($array[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
       echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
        }
     echo "}<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array variable name is the $array. So you can access  `center_strength` just like  `$array[0]['center_strength']` and if you want iterate over all elements:

```
foreach($array as $single_arr) {
   //Now $single_arr contain the inner array
   foreach($single_arr as $key => $value) {
     //for first item: $key= center_id , $value=103
   }
}
```